# How do I align Label and Input on the same line to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling while trying to locate 2 buttons on the left of an input field.
I already tried several suggestions on the internet but I couldn't make it the way I want.

```
<div class="col-xs-6" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <div class="search" style="height: 18px" ng-if="vm.showSearch()">
                    <form style="margin:0px" name="filter_actions"  novalidate>
                        <div>
                            <input id="freeTextSearch" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" autofocus ng-change="vm.filterTable(Search)" ng-model="Search"
                                   style="text-indent: 5px;"  minlength="1" ng-model-options="{debounce:100}" id="Search" name="Search" placeholder="Search fields">
                            <a ng-show="Search" ng-click="localSearch = ''; vm.filterTable(localSearch)"><i style="vertical-align: middle; top:4px; right:35px; position: absolute" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <label class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="vm.popUp()"><i class="fa fa-expand" style="color:darkgreen;"></i></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like :

[image]

Comment: You could use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)for this.
It's easier for us to help if you strip your code from framework-related stuff or include a code snippet with the framework & variables included so we have a working example to inspect.

Comment: Can you post the full HTML/CSS code? Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind, that `label` is an inline element similar to `span`, so you need to set its css to `display: inline-block` to behave like a `div`

once you have done this, the easiest way to have them in the same line is to use `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: nowrap` on the parent div.

here is my favorite [flex-cheat-sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I have simplified your example and you can see how this works clicking below on Run code snippet.

```css
.pull-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.pull-right input{  border: 1px solid green;}
.pull-right label{ border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <div class="search" style="height: 18px" ng-if="vm.showSearch()">
    <form style="margin:0px" name="filter_actions" novalidate>
      <div>
        <input id="freeTextSearch" type="text" 
        class="form-control input-sm" autofocus ng-change="vm.filterTable(Search)" 
        ng-model="Search" 
        style="text-indent: 5px;" minlength="1" 
        ng-model-options="{debounce:100}" id="Search" name="Search" placeholder="Search fields">
        <a ng-show="Search" 
        ng-click="localSearch = ''; vm.filterTable(localSearch)">
        <i style="vertical-align: middle; top:4px; right:35px; position: absolute" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">      </i></a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <label class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="vm.popUp()"><i class="fa fa-expand" style="color:darkgreen;">your icons</i></label>
  </div>
</div>
```